# Getting a 302 in shell but not in browser

Tags: html, http, wget

When I try to get a wget request of page 430 I get a redirect 302.

```
wget "https://www.zalando.be/kleding/?p=430"
```

results in

```
HTTP-verzoek is sent; waiting on answer... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: /kleding/?p=429 [following...]
--2018-11-10 21:08:57--  https://www.zalando.be/kleding/?p=429
```

However, when I access the site and push on the button for next page, then it goes to "https://www.zalando.be/kleding/?p=430".

I don't understand how this is possible, can someone elaborate this for me?

Also is it possible to do this in the shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that accessing by either `wget` or directly writing in the browser's address bar the site's URL for **p** values greater than 429 will trigger a **302 redirect**.

This doesn't happen while pressing the **next** button because in this way the page content is loaded through AJAX. This is an example of a request being made when clicking the **next** button: https://www.zalando.be/api/catalog/articles?categories=kleding&limit=84&offset=36036&sort=popularity

I suggest investigating the paging logic for some conditional that may trigger the redirect as an out of range page request protection.

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong.

It seems that when reloading the page several times, the contents change. The fact that the browser also receives a 302 code when going to [www.zalando.be/kleding/?p=430](https://www.zalando.be/kleding/?p=430) means there is a server side "problem" with the dynamic content. I don't know how Zalando works, but my best guess is that the popularity sort throws the system off. When the system doesn't know the right amount of entries, it then redirects to page 429 (as evidenced by 431 also redirecting).

<s>This is probably a very temporary redirect because I cannot reproduce the problem.</s>

Comment: So you can wget "https://www.zalando.be/kleding/?p=430" without getting page 429?